# Acceptable use of typedef in class?

Tags: c++

Is this an acceptable use of typedef in the class, Inventory?

**Inventory.h**

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H

#include "Item.h"
#include <unordered_map>

class Inventory
{
public:
    typedef std::unordered_map<Item, int> ItemTable; ///< Items and their quantities

    const ItemTable& items() const;
    void add_item(Item item, int quantity);
    int quantity(Item item);
    bool remove_item(Item item, int quantity);

private:
    ItemTable items_;
};

#endif
```

**Inventory.cpp**

```
#include "Inventory.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include <cstddef>

const Inventory::ItemTable& Inventory::items() const
{
    return items_;
}

void Inventory::add_item(Item item, int quantity)
{
    int total_of_item = items_[item];
    items_[item] = total_of_item + quantity;
}

int Inventory::quantity(Item item)
{
    return items_[item];
}

bool Inventory::remove_item(Item item, int quantity)
{
    int total_of_item = items_[item];

    if (quantity > total_of_item) {
        return false;
    }

    items_[item] = total_of_item - quantity;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Normally, I absolutely hate typeset but you've used it very nicely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. I like it because it will make maintenance easier.

If you change the type of the container then you only need to change it in one place in the code. I would even go and define other things in relation to the typedef.

```
// For example:
typedef ItemTable::iterator         Iter;
typedef ItemTable::const_iterator   CIter;
```

But I would not expose the internal object with this:

```
const Inventory::ItemTable& Inventory::items() const
```

Any object that uses this method not becomes very tightly bound to this interface. I would question the need for this functionality. I prefer to expose methods that manipulate the object as a whole.

An alternative is to expose the iterators. Iterators are a much looser coupling.

As a result I would make `ItemTable` a private type. While the `Iter` and `CIter` would be public.

#### Edit:

```
class X
{
    typedef std::vector<int>            Cont;
    Cont        data;

    public:
        typedef Cont::iterator          Iter;
        typedef Cont::const_iterator    CIter;


        Iter begin()        { return data.begin();}
        Iter end()          { return data.end();}

        CIter begin() const { return data.begin();}
        CIter end()   const { return data.end();}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I just have a little convention question regarding your answer: Where should I place the private typedef so the public two iterator typedefs can see it?

Comment: @kisplit: See edit.

Answer (score 2):

Very much so. It reduces typing on your part and increases readability on the reader's part.

Comment: It also reduces maintenance effort.  I think that's the big win, here.